# ASP.NET user control designer support

Tags: c#, asp.net, designer

I have a user control which when added to the markup via the Toolbox or manually typing 
`<myNameSpc:myCtrl ...` I would like to spit out:

```
<myNameSpc:myCtrl>

     <template></template>

</myNameSpc:myCtrl>
```

I remember doing this for windows workflows and it involved implementing something like a TypeConverter and WorkflowXmlSerializer so it maybe possible for user controls as well I'd guess ? the only thing is that I don't have time to research this matter now, so I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction so that I don't have to dig deep into the designer serialization of VS (which I remember was a big pain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your custom control, you can specify a `ToolboxDataAttribute` which defines the default html that will be generated when you drag a control onto the design service. E.g.:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:myCtrl runat="server"><template></template></{0}:myCtrl>")]
public class myCtrl : System.Web.UI.Control
{

}
```

Comment: Great thank you - this works for the Toolbox so 50% is solved:) I can't vote you up unfortunately but I really appreciate your help! Thank you again.

Comment: Accepted. How can I accept the Eugene's answer as well ? I think it's the other 50% missing.

Answer (score 2):

For the manual generation you can create a [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx). The best way to do that is find existing ASPX snippet and modify it to gen your control. I'm assuming you are using VS 2010.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try today (I think it will work which will also solve the intellisence help message I'd like to show as well). Thanks